# Зачем в JUnit тесте 2 инициализирующих и 2 завершающих метода

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, тестирование, junit

Создал JUnit тест (впервые), обнаружил что создалось 2 инициализирующих класс и два завершающих метода:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownClass() {
}

@Before
public void setUp() {
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
}
```

1. Чем отличаются @BeforeClass, @AfterClass от @Before, @After?
2. В какой момент запускаются инициализаторы? перед каждым вызовом тестирующих методов, или единожды в начале?
3. Для чего и в каких случаях нужны @AfterClass и @After?

Comment: Ну раз вам название не намекает, то попробуйте написать в каждый метод вывод в консоль, и все станет ясно. :) Первое исполняется [однократно](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html), второе [до или после каждого теста](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@BeforeClass` выполняется до теста. тут выполняют инициализацию глобальных переменных, считывание данных из переменной окружения среды и т.п. выполняется 1 раз вначале

`@Before` выполняется до каждого метода с аннотацией @Test. Можно использовать для создания папки, где будет тест с аннотацией @Test создавать файл

`@After` выполняется после каждого метода с аннотацией @Test. Можно использовать для удаления файлов и папки, которую создали выше. можно использовать, как сепаратор логов

`@AfterClass`  выполняется после вызовов всех методов с аннотацией @Test, то есть в конце теста. используется для сбора логов, зачистки данных...

```
    import org.junit.*;

public class BasicAnnotationTest {

    // Run once, e.g. Database connection, connection pool
    @BeforeClass
    public static void runOnceBeforeClass() {
        System.out.println("@BeforeClass - runOnceBeforeClass");
    }

    // Run once, e.g close connection, cleanup
    @AfterClass
    public static void runOnceAfterClass() {
        System.out.println("@AfterClass - runOnceAfterClass");
    }

    // Should rename to @BeforeTestMethod
    // e.g. Creating an similar object and share for all @Test
    @Before
    public void runBeforeTestMethod() {
        System.out.println("@Before - runBeforeTestMethod");
    }

    // Should rename to @AfterTestMethod
    @After
    public void runAfterTestMethod() {
        System.out.println("@After - runAfterTestMethod");
    }

    @Test
    public void test_method_1() {
        System.out.println("@Test - test_method_1");
    }

    @Test
    public void test_method_2() {
        System.out.println("@Test - test_method_2");
    }

}
```

Output

```
@BeforeClass - runOnceBeforeClass

@Before - runBeforeTestMethod
@Test - test_method_1
@After - runAfterTestMethod

@Before - runBeforeTestMethod
@Test - test_method_2
@After - runAfterTestMethod

@AfterClass - runOnceAfterClass
```